# What is bit-true implementation

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, communication

What is bit-true implementation (with an example if possible)?

I was reading a paper and it was stated "a bit-true implementation of the algorithm on a FPGA was performed." So what exactly is bit-true implementation and how is it implemented on FPGA?

Comment: reference? which paper?

Comment: The term "bit-true implementation" of an algorithm means low-level details of the FPGA design were validated against the design intentions. For example, perhaps the exact width of each part of every numeric calculation was checked to prevent overflow/underflow. This term isn't a specific FPGA design method, it just refers to validating the low-level details of the FPGA design.

Comment: More to the point, "bit true" (or more commonly, "bit-accurate") means that the data produced by the FPGA implementation can be compared bit-for-bit with the results of some other implementation. Normally, you need to allow for variations in the LSBs of result values because of slight differences in the arithmetic implementations.